# What is the Perl context with range operator?

Tags: perl

I'm a Perl newbie. I want to understand Perl context in conjunction with range operator. This is my code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $asc = ( 10 .. 50 );
print "$asc\n";
```

I have two doubts.

1. If the expression ( 10 .. 50 ) returns an array, then, as it's a scalar context, "asc" variable should be assigned the length of the array, that is, 41.
2. If expression ( 10 ..50 ) returns a list, then, as it's a scalar context, "asc" variable should be assigned the last item from the list, that is, 50.

But, I get the following shout ..

```
Use of uninitialized value in range (or flip) at main.pl line ..
```

Appreciate and welcome any guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're working with the [Range Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in an scalar context, which is otherwise known as the flip-flop operator.

You should read the entire documentation, but the following excerpts are relevant to your situation:

> In scalar context, "`..`" returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a **flip-flop**, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors.
>
> ...
>
> If either operand of scalar "`..`" is a constant expression, that operand is considered true if it is equal (`==`) to the current input line number (the `$.` variable).

The “exact“ error message explains what's going on:

```
Use of uninitialized value $. in range (or flip)
```

Basically, Perl interprets this usage as a flip/flop test.

It's testing if the current line number `$.` is equal to the integer values you specified:

```
my $asc = ( $. == 10 .. $. == 50 );
```

However, because you haven't read from a file handle, the `$.` variable is uninitialized and throws a warning.

#### Achieving a List Context

It is possible to get the list context behavior that you described, but you'll need to adjust the code to make your intent more explicit:

```
my $count = () = (10..50);          # Forces a list context
my $last_element = (10..50)[-1];    # Also forces a list context

print "$count\n";
print "$last_element\n";
```

Outputs:

```
41
50
```

Answer (score 6):

> *If the expression ( 10 .. 50 ) returns an array, then, as it's a scalar context, ...*
>
> *If expression ( 10 ..50 ) returns a list, then, as it's a scalar context, ...*

You're operating on some very incorrect misconceptions.

- It's impossible to return an array<sup>[1]</sup>. The only thing that can be returned is zero or more scalars. In scalar context, that list must be exactly one scalar long.
- Scalar context causes the operator to change what it returns; it doesn't cause the returned value to be coerced into a scalar.

[Each operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416) decides what it returns in each context. Some, like the range operator (`..`), even change behaviour based on context. In fact, the behaviour of the range operator in scalar context is significantly different than its behaviour in list context. So much so, that's it's usually called by a different name when it's in scalar context: the flip-flop operator.

This question isn't really about the flip-flop operator, so I'm not going to go into too much detail. (The documentation for it is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).) Suffice it to say it can be used to selectively print lines by number with very little code.

For example,

```
while (<DATA>) {
   print if 2..3;
}

__DATA__
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

outputs

```
bbb
ccc
```

Part of the "magic" involve comparing the numbers provided against [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.), the line number of the last line read. That means that

```
my $ac = 10..50;
```

is short for

```
my $ac = ($. == 10) .. ($. == 50);
```

Since you never read from a file, `$.` is undefined.

---

1. When you do `return @array;`, you either return the elements of the array (`$array[0], $array[1], ...`) or its length depending on context.