# What is "Use of unitialized value $. in range (or flip)" trying to tell me in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code snippet in Perl:

```
my $argsize = @args;
if ($argsize >1){
    foreach my $a ($args[1..$argsize-1]) {
    $a =~ s/(.*[-+*].*)/\($1\)/; # if there's a math operator, put in parens
    }
}
```

On execution I'm getting "Use of unitialized value $. in range (or flip) , followed by Argument "" isn't numeric in array element at... both pointing to the foreach line.

Can someone help me decipher the error message (and fix the problem(s))?  I have an array @args of strings.  The code should loop through the second to n't elements (if any exist), and  surround individual args with () if they contain a +,-, or *.

I don't think the error stems from the values in args, I think I'm screwing up the range somehow... but I'm failing when args has > 1 element.  an example might be:

```
<"bla bla bla">  <x-1>  <foo>
```

Comment: `($args[1..$argsize-1])` => `(@args)` or possibly `(@args[1..$#args])` Parens are not metachars in replacment part so you don't need to escape them `/($1)/` `use diagnostics;` will give you very verbose explanation of error message.

Comment: Can you give an example of `@args`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The long and short of it is - your foreach line *is* broken:

```
foreach my $a (@args[1..$argsize-1]) {
```

Works fine. It's because you're using a `$` which says 'scalar value' rather than an `@` which says array (or list).

If you `use diagnostics` you get;

> Use of uninitialized value $. in range (or flip) at
>      (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>
> To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
>       the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
>       it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
>       undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
>       and the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
>       literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
>       optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
>       concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
>       your program.

You can reproduce this error by:

```
my $x = 1..3;
```

Which is actually pretty much what you're doing here - you're trying to assign an array value into a scalar.

There's a load more detail in this question:

[What is the Perl context with range operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175653/what-is-the-perl-context-with-range-operator)

But basically: It's treating it as a range operator, as if you were working your way through a file. You would be able to 'act on' particular lines in the file via this operator.

e.g.:

```
use Data::Dumper;
while (<DATA>) {
    my $x = 2 .. 3;
    print Dumper $x;
    print if $x;
}

__DATA__
line one
another line
third line
fourth line
```

That range operator is testing line numbers - and because you have no line numbers (because you're not iterating a file) it errors. (But otherwise - it *might* work, but you'd get some *really* strange results ;))

But I'd suggest you're doing this quite a convoluted way, and making (potentially?) an error, in that you're starting your array at 1, not zero.

You could instead:

```
s/(.*[-+*].*)/\($1\)/ for @args;
```

Which'll have the same result.

(If you need to skip the first argument:

```
my ( $first_arg, @rest ) = @args; 
s/(.*[-+*].*)/\($1\)/ for @rest;
```

But that error at runtime is the result of some of the data you're feeding in. What you've got here though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @args =  ( '<"bla bla bla">',  '<x-1>',  '<foo>' );

print "Before @args\n";
s/(.*[-+*].*)/\($1\)/ for @args;
print "After: @args\n";
```

Comment: Ah perl, it's such an adventure using you... but thanks your suggestion completely solved my underlying problem, so I have voted you up and accepted the answer.  I would still like to understand the error better, but que cera cera.  I like the new code much better -- I can't help but write c-style perl code.

Comment: I've had a bit of a dig - `my $x = 1..3;` does the same thing, I think for the same reason. Specifically - you're _trying_ to squidge a sequence of values into a single one. The biggest thing that I found useful to understand is the sigil at the start of the variable isn't 'what it contains' but 'what I'm getting out'. So you _always_ access a single value as `$` regardless of whether it's an array or hash element.

Comment: awesome.  Thanks so much.  I gotta say, My ability to use perl effectively has been greatly improved thanks to SO and guys like you.

Comment: Ah, got it. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175653/what-is-the-perl-context-with-range-operator (Example edited into answer)